# Distribute posts evenly across two sidebars, and for each item, output only if it exists

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to distribute posts across two sidebars.  There can be up to 10 posts, but there may be less.  The posts are ordered by date, and they need to be equally distributed between the two sidebars in that order.  *(First post in left sidebar, second post in right sidebar, and so on)*

Currently, I am getting the posts and saving them to an array.  For the left sidebar, I check all even posts (starting at `0`, up to `8`), and output the post if it exists.  I do the same with the odd posts (`1` to `9`) in the right sidebar.

However I am looking for a more efficient way to do this by looping through the array, and checking only the even/odd posts.

This is my code for one sidebar:

```
<?php $posts = query_posts("posts_per_page=10&cat=1340"); 

 if($posts != null) {

 $ad = object_to_array($posts);?>

 <?php if($ad[1]) {?>
  <br />
  <a href="<?php echo get_field('link',$ad[1]['ID']); ?>" target="_blank"> <span class="ad1" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_featured_image_url($ad[1]["ID"],"large");?>')"></span></a>
<?php } ?>

<?php if($ad[3]) {?>
 <br />
 <a href="<?php echo get_field('link',$ad[3]['ID']); ?>" target="_blank"> <span class="ad1" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_featured_image_url($ad[3]["ID"],"large");?>')"></span></a>
<?php } ?>

<?php if($ad[5]) {?>
  <br />
  <a href="<?php echo get_field('link',$ad[5]['ID']); ?>" target="_blank"> <span class="ad1" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_featured_image_url($ad[5]["ID"],"large");?>')"></span></a>
<?php } ?>

<?php if($ad[7]) {?>
 <br />
 <a href="<?php echo get_field('link',$ad[7]['ID']); ?>" target="_blank"> <span class="ad1" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_featured_image_url($ad[7]["ID"],"large");?>')"></span></a>
<?php } ?>

<?php if($ad[9]) {?>
 <br />
 <a href="<?php echo get_field('link',$ad[9]['ID']); ?>" target="_blank"> <span class="ad1" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_featured_image_url($ad[9]["ID"],"large");?>')"></span></a>
<?php } ?>


<?php } ?>
```

This works.  However, I would like to somehow loop through the even/odd posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple for loop with a MOD check on the index would solve your problem:
Your code doesn't show how you are aligning the html code on left and right, so I will provide the PHP code to print the odd/even rows and you figure it out the html part. I added a check to add a CSS class for the odd/even code.

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($ad); $i++){
    echo '<a class="' . ($i%2==0?'EvenClass':'OddClass') . 
          '" href="' . get_field('link',$ad[$i]['ID']) .
          '" target="_blank"> <span class="ad1" style="background-image:url(\'' . 
          get_featured_image_url($ad[$i]["ID"],"large") .'\')"></span></a>';
}
```

So, as per you comment you already have the odd and even divs. Just duplicate the above (although I still prefer my solution, with a little fix you can output the divs from this code).

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($ad); $i++){
    if ($i%2==0){ //Even values
        echo '<a href="' . get_field('link',$ad[$i]['ID']) .
              '" target="_blank"> <span class="ad1" style="background-image:url(\'' . 
              get_featured_image_url($ad[$i]["ID"],"large") .'\')"></span></a>';
    }
}
```

And another for

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($ad); $i++){
    if ($i%2!=0){ //odd values
        echo '<a href="' . get_field('link',$ad[$i]['ID']) .
              '" target="_blank"> <span class="ad1" style="background-image:url(\'' . 
              get_featured_image_url($ad[$i]["ID"],"large") .'\')"></span></a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using a CSS class to align them.  I have two separate `div`s with the content and styling for the sidebars.  Within the `div` for the right sidebar, I need to output only the odd posts, and elsewhere in my code, in the `div` for the left sidebar I need to output the even posts.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone who took the time to look into my question.  I have found a solution.

This is how I solved the issue:

For the left side, I use the following loop, which only loops through the even posts, and checks if they exist before outputting:

```
 <?php for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) { if(($ad[$i]) && ($i%2 == 0)) {?>
  <br />
  <a href="<?php echo get_field('link',$ad[$i]['ID']); ?>" target="_blank"> <span class="ad1" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_featured_image_url($ad[$i]["ID"],"large");?>')"></span></a>
<?php } } } ?>
```

And for the right side, I do the same with `$1%2 == 1` to check for, and output only the odd posts.